# Cucumber selenium testng getting error in testrunner

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, cucumber, cucumber-java, testng-dataprovider

```
package Runner;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.testng.FeatureWrapper;
import io.cucumber.testng.PickleWrapper;
import io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;

@CucumberOptions(
        features="src/test/resources/features",
        glue="steps"
      // plugin={"pretty", "io.qameta.allure.cucumber7jvm.AllureCucumber7Jvm"}
      //  tags="@Amazon"
)
public class TestRunner   {
    
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Scenarios", dataProvider = "scenarios")
    public void scenario(PickleWrapper pickle, FeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickle.getPickle());
    }

    @DataProvider(name="myFeature")
    public Object[][] getFeatures()
    {
        
        if(testNGCucumberRunner==null) {
            
            testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
        }
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }
}
```

I've tried this:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@CucumberOptions(features={"src//main//java//features"}
        ,glue={"stepdefinations","utility"}
        ,plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"}
        , tags ={"@appium"}
)
@Test
public class RunTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{

}
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
[Utils] [ERROR] [Error] java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke &quot;io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios()&quot; because &quot;this.testNGCucumberRunner&quot; is null
    at Runner.TestRunner.scenarios(TestRunner.java:33)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:55)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:45)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:115)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:509)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1308)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1036)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```